# How can I redirect URI of type (example.com/?a=100) via htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The main problem I'm having is that there is not a file present like "index.php".

I want to handle request of type: **example.com/?a=100**

I've tried something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}% ^\?p=825$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/redirected.html [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the **?** from your %{QUERY_STRING} pattern :

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=825$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/redirected.html? [R=301,L]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the destination url is important as it discards the orignal query strings.

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: Thanks, I've had already tried without the question mark, nevertheless my mistake was in the "%{QUERY_STRING}%".

I added a "%" symbol at the end.